# The constructor Notification(int, String, long) is undefined

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification right from the Main Activity.

Here is my code -

```
public class Notification extends Activity{

private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1987;
private int count=0;
private NotificationManager mgr=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notifyMe();

  }


public void notifyMe(){

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Notification text that will be shown on status bar.", 
        System.currentTimeMillis());

// The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this
// notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Notification.this,
        0, new Intent(Notification.this, MainActivity.class), 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(Notification.this, "Content Title", "Content text",
        contentIntent);
mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

But I get the following error: The constructor Notification(int, String, long) is undefined

The line where I get the error is the following:

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Notification text that will be shown on status bar.", 
        System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the constructor of [Android Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).. The problem lies on your activity name which is also `Notification`. You should change to other name to resolve the problem.

Instead of changing your activity name, you can include the package to make system clear which **Notification** to use. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890786/1465828) provide by user system32.

Answer (score 1):

```
android.app.Notification notification 
                = new android.app.Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
```

I suggest to rename that activity to `NotificationActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Notification.Builder` to create a Notification as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html).

Comment: does it work with older android versions?
I'd still like to know what mistake I'm doing in this code.

Comment: Yes previous constructor should work also but with API 9+ only. what API are you compiling against ?

Comment: Just tried it myself, no issues. Check imports and clean project.